# fetch URL from JSON and display data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have an web app where you can search for repositories by name. It displays some of the info but I want to display the readme file if the repo has one. I know I need to fetch it separately but I'm not 100% sure how to do that. How do I fetch it and display it as another list object.

This is the working code without readme.

```js
let searchTerm;

class SearchBox extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      repositories: [],
      showInfo: false
    };

  }


  render() {
    const moreDetail = (item) => (!this.state.showInfo ? < span / > :
      <
      div className = "info" >
      <
      li >
      <
      p > Open issue count: {
        item.open_issues_count
      } < /p> <
      /li> <
      li >
      <
      p > Number of forks: {
        item.forks
      } < /p> <
      /li> <
      li >
      <
      p > Language: {
        item.language
      } < /p> <
      /li> <
      /div>
    );

    return ( <
      div >
      <
      form >
      <
      input type = "text"
      className = "searchbox"
      ref = {
        (input) => {
          this.searchBox = input;
        }
      }
      /> <
      button onClick = {
        this.onClick
      } > Search < /button> <
      /form> <
      div className = "results" >
      <
      h2 > Repositories < /h2> <
      button onClick = {
        this._handleClick.bind(this)
      } > Detailed view < /button> <
      /div> <
      ul > {
        this.state.repositories.map((item, index) => ( <
          div className = "repository"
          key = {
            index
          } >
          <
          a href = {
            item.html_url
          } > < li className = "repoName" > {
            item.name
          }

          <
          /li> <
          /a> {
            moreDetail(item)
          }


          <
          /div>
        ))
      } <
      /ul>

      <
      /div>
    );
  }

  _handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      showInfo: !this.state.showInfo
    });
  }


  onClick(event) {

    searchTerm = this.searchBox.value;
    let endpoint = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?sort=stars&order=desc&q=' + searchTerm;

    console.log(searchTerm);
    fetch(endpoint)
      .then(blob => blob.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          repositories: response.items
        });
      });
    event.preventDefault();

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

I am making a webapp using Github search API. When searching for a repository it should display the repository and info about that including the readme file.
so far it does all that apart from displaying the readme file.

Comment: maybe you're looking for the `filter` function? And then just looking to see if `item.name === "readme"` or something

Comment: No, I would have to fetch the readme file since it's another URL. In the JSON I get from the current AJAX request I get url. so the url for this would be {item.url}/readme but I simply don't know how to fetch that and display that.

Comment: so why can't you do `fetch(item.url + "/readme")`?

Comment: I might be able to do that but how do I display that together with the rest of the content?

Comment: just add it to the item using setstate like you're doing? And then just put that somewhere.

Comment: Can you please show me how the code would look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137095/discussion-between-naomi-and-a-lau).